# mysql multiple similar table query[seems not duplicate]

Tags: mysql

I have a sales software that use MYSQL database and i want to make a web extension using PHP. the software creating a new table everyday for every days transaction with same column but name like sales_data_Yearmonthday.
e.g
sales_data_20190122
sales_data_20190123
sales_data_20190124
sales_data_20190125
sales_data_20190126
sales_data_20190127
sales_data_20190128
So my question is what will be the best way to query these table if i want to get sales report for last 7 days?
**UNION ALL** is one option to join all table but are there any other option to do that for getting best performance as 356 table will be created every year and each table may have contain over 5000 records.

its may not the best database design but i cannot change it.

Comment: "I want to make"...."I cannot change it" - I am confused. It's "not the best database design" in fact it is probably the worst possible design. If you said you wanted to chop your arm off (even though you don't want to) and asked for the best solution, how should we answer?

Comment: I want to make a web extension using this database. i didn't design this software as well its database. thats why i can not change it.

Comment: LImit the tables you need to union by generating the date extension based on now() or current_date or whatever the php equivalent is.

Comment: That is my initial thought like SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM sales_data_20190122
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM sales_data_20190123
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM sales_data_20190124....

Comment: Assuming the past data don't change  Why not a cron that build  a periodical /history table (month or year) adding the date to each row  ??

Answer (score 1):

Given the specified constraints (as unfortunate as that situation is)...

using `UNION ALL` is the most appropriate solution to satisfying the specification.

If we are wanting the "past seven days", then we (our code) needs to figure out which tables will be required (vs the tables that would be required e.g. "so far this month") and dynamically construct SQL text.

We first write the query against one table, get that tested.

```
SELECT t.fee
     , t.fi
     , t.fo
     , t.fum
  FROM sales_data_20190128 t 
 WHERE t.foo = ?
```

Then we just repeat that query for each table that might included rows we are interested in, excluding tables we know for sure will not contain rows we want, and combine the queries with `UNION ALL` set operator.

If we need the whole set ordered, then wrap each SELECT in parens, and finish with an ORDER BY clause. e.g.

```
( SELECT t.fee, t.fi, t.fo, t.fum
    FROM sales_data_20190124 t
   WHERE t.foo = ?
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT t.fee, t.fi, t.fo, t.fum
    FROM sales_data_20190125
   WHERE t.foo = ?
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT t.fee, t.fi, t.fo, t.fum
    FROM sales_data_20190126 t
   WHERE t.foo = ?
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT t.fee, t.fi, t.fo, t.fum
    FROM sales_data_20190127 t
   WHERE t.foo = ?
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT t.fee, t.fi, t.fo, t.fum
   FROM sales_data_20190128 t
  WHERE t.foo = ?
)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

---

Do *NOT* try to simplify the code by creating view that concatenates all of the tables together, and query against that. Don't do that.

---

Comment: Thanks for reply. this is what i have done so far. and your answer made me confident that "UNION ALL" is only best way to go.